# Sending a successful POST request via RestAssured Java does not assign value to "id", but sending the request via Postman does

Tags: json, rest-assured

I am relatively new to API automation and currently I am developing my first framework with RestAssured Java. I've been researching the issue for a few days without any success, so if you can provide any advice, I would be very thankful.

The following behavior is present via **Postman**:

Endpoint: POST /api/Teachers
**Request Body**:

```
{
  "teacherName": "string",
  "teacherSubject": "string",
  "teacherPhone": "string"
}
```

Upon submitting the request via Postman, the **Response Body** is:

**201 Created**

```
{
  "teacherName": "string",
  "teacherSubject": "string",
  "teacherPhone": "string",
  "teacherId": int (auto-assigned)
}
```

When I execute the same request via **RestAssured Java** (+Cucumber BDD), I still get Response Code 201 Created and a response body, however the "teacherId" is always 0. (int)

**201 Created**

```
{
  "teacherName": "string",
  "teacjerSubject": "string",
  "teacherPhone": "string",
  "teacherId": 0
}
```

In my framework I've tried submitting the details via my TestData.class, and also hardcoding them but the result is the same.

If you have any additional ideas or advice on things I could try debugging this, please share.

Another strange thing I have noticed is that when I GET /api/Teachers it always returns an array list of 10 JSON blocks. I played around a bit with the API and if I try to get /api/Teachers/{id} which is bigger than 10 I am able to successfully access those details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue - it turns out that it was due to backend validation for the existence of which I was not aware.

I was sending random strings with my tests such as:

```
String teacherName =  "teacher name " + random.nextInt;
```

The request was still successful in this case, but the teacherId was not assigned, and it always returned 0.

In order not to hardcore the values so my test is valid each time when I run my framework, I used the following:

```
String teacherName =  "teacher name " + random.nextInt(bound: 999);
```

Now my request passes again with 200 OK but I also have the value for the teacherId returned.

Answer (score 0):

Please try 3 things:

1. Change teacherId field type from int to Integer
2. Make sure you have valid setter and getter for this field
3. Make sure there is no typo in the field name